# WFFM Detailed Reports tab in form report is showing blank

Tags: wffm, sxa

Yes this is a bug and sitecore support have registered the appropriate bug in the current version of the WFFM module. Please use the reference number 87110 for this bug.

They suggested us to hide this tab in CMS only mode.To hide the "Detailed Reports" tab, you can perform the following steps:

- go to the "/sitecore/client/Applications/WFFM/Pages/FormReport/PageSettings/TabControl/Detailed Reports" item in the "core" database,
- check the "IsHidden" field and save the item.

When i check the IsHidden field .The Detailed reports tab hidden. but i need to Show the the data in Detailed Reports Tabs Any idea about